# Objective-C ivar visibility 'package'

Tags: objective-c

When creating ivars in Objective-C the default visibility is 'protected', meaning the ivar can be accessed from subclasses. (If it is declared in the header).

Therefore this code:

```
@interface MagicCarpet : NSObject
{

@protected
    NSString* _threadCount;
}
```

is the same as this:

```
@interface MagicCarpet : NSObject
{
    NSString* _threadCount;
}
```

Apparently, there's also a 'package' level visibility. I frequently see and use 'public', 'private' and 'protected' visibilities. . . have never seen any code with 'package'. What does it do?

Comment: no. you can't "frequently see and use 'public', 'private' and 'protected' visibilities". because ivar shouldn't be in .h file at all (unless for legacy code). use property for public ivar, hide privates in .m file, avoid protected when possible.

Comment: @BryanChen I agree on adhering to the modern Objc conventions - this way there's no surprises with KVO, etc. . But the point of the question was about what 'package' visibility does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Apple docs:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/Cocoa/RN-ObjectiveC/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004309-CH1-DontLinkElementID_7)

> `@package` is a new instance variable protection class, like `@public`
>   and `@protected`. `@package` instance variables behave as follows:
>
> - `@public` in 32-bit;
> - `@public` in 64-bit, inside the framework that    defined the class;
> - `@private` in 64-bit, outside the framework that defined the class.
>
>   In 64-bit, the instance variable symbol for an `@package` ivar is not
>     exported, so any attempt to use the ivar from outside the framework
>     that defined the class will fail with a link error.

This logic seems quite confusing, so I'm not at all surprised that `@package` is not commonly used.

Comment: 32-bit means old runtime and 64-bit means modern runtime. In modern runtime, it is which basically same as `package` in Java or `internal` in C#

Comment: `@package` is useful for framework authors. It's not useful for apps.